# Unable to locate the parent Id properly using the Parent method in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a GridView control embeeded inside a div as under

```
<div id="parentDiv">
        Hello how r u
        <p>
            <asp:GridView ID="grdView" runat="server">
            </asp:GridView>
        </p>
    </div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is that, to find the Parent element of the grid (which is the "parentDiv") and set the background color to green.My code(does not work)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var parentElement = $('#grdView').parent("div");
    parentElement.css("background-color", "#ffaaaa");
});​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relatively to the GridView, you'd better use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method:

```
var parentElement = $("#grdView").closest("#parentDiv");  // or $("#parentDiv")
```

It will get the corresponding `div` better than `parent()`, since the parent node of the GridView is `p` element.

---

**UPDATE.** In order to set background to the text only, you have to place it in personal `span` or `div` tag:

```
<div id="parentDiv">
    <span>Hello how r u</span>
    <p>
        <asp:GridView ID="grdView" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
    </p>
</div>
```

And then use the following JavaScript code:

```
var parentElement = $("#grdView").closest("#parentDiv").children("span");
         // or just $("#parentDiv").children("span");
```

Comment: The entire thing background has now been set. All the child elements of div

Comment: Yes, but what else do you expect of setting background color to the parent element?

Comment: Expected output: only "Hello how r u" background will be set and not grid

Comment: I think you should have specified this expecting result on the question

Comment: @user1323981 then set the <p> background to white

Comment: @gdoron Yeah, it makes sense only if it is used in relative way.

Answer (score 0):

since `grdView` 's parent is a `p` element, maybe you should change

```
 var parentElement = $('#grdView').closest("div");
```

Further reference: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

use also camelCase notation here:

```
 .css("backgroundColor", "#ffaaaa");
```

and if you need to give a green background only to the immediate textnodes just override the background color on `p` element

```
$('#parentDiv > p').css("backgroundColor", "<other color here>");
```

Comment: same result. It is setting the background color of the grid. and I need to use parent

Comment: No change Sir.Same result.  var parentElement = $('#grdView').closest("div");
            parentElement.css("backgroundColor", "#ffaaaa");

Answer (score 0):

**My code(does not work) -** because id is not gridview if you write `runat="server"` see the id in the source, I think it'll be ContentPlaceHolder1_grdView or something like that

```
$(document).ready(function () {           

            var parentElement = $('#grdView').parent("div");
            parentElement.css("background-color", "#ffaaaa");


        });
```

Answer (score 0):

To give the illusion that the containing element is colored without affect ting the grid, you'll need to color the grid the same color as the background.

```
$("#grdView").css("backgroundColor",$("body").css("backgroundColor"));
$("#grdView").closest("div").css("backgroundColor","#ffaaaa");
```